# Simpleform not rendering a Devise model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

When I try to render 'form', nothing shows up.

HTML I put inside of my _form.html.slim shows up eg.

```
h1 TESTING

= simple_form_for(@park, html: {class: 'form-horizontal', role: 'form'}) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :email
  ...
  = f.input :website
  p
  = f.button :submit
```

But a form with no fields is rendered on the html.

Why is my simple form not rendering?

Comment: Can you post a little more of your form code?

Comment: @Jay uploaded more of the code.

Comment: Looks like you are using haml,then why is your file name is `_form.html.slim`?